# RHEL Virtual Machine - sslv3 alert certificate expired + 403 errors on yum update

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel

I've got two RHEL VMs. VM1 and VM2.

VM2 started life as VM1 and has since been personalized.

VM1 has been left as it is for months.

I found that when trying a > yum update on VM1, I would get a message about "sslv3 alert certificate expired" followed by every single repo failing with a 403 forbidden error.

At the same time, VM2 is able to yum update just fine.

Following another post I found, I run subscription-manager list --consumed to get this:

VM2 (working)

```
$ subscription-manager list --consumed
+-------------------------------------------+
Consumed Subscriptions
+-------------------------------------------+
Subscription Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, Standard (1-2 sockets) (Unlimited guests)
Provides: Oracle Java (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Software Collections Beta (for RHEL Server)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Red Hat Beta
SKU: RH0192098F3
Contract: 10003384
Account: 1259084
Serial: 3566340574775756298
Pool ID: 8a85f9813a1de8b9013a2f9bfb876377
Active: True
Quantity Used: 1
Service Level: STANDARD
Service Type: L1-L3
Status Details: 
Starts: 08/10/12
Ends: 08/10/15
System Type: Virtual
```

VM1 (Not working)

```
$ subscription-manager list --consumed
+-------------------------------------------+
   Consumed Subscriptions
+-------------------------------------------+

Subscription Name:      Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, Standard (1-2 sockets)
                        (Unlimited guests)
Provides:               Red Hat Software Collections Beta (for RHEL Server)
                        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
                        Red Hat Beta
SKU:                    RH0192098F3
Contract:               10003384
Account:                1259084
Serial Number:          7042773144247234664
Active:                 True
Quantity Used:          1
Service Level:          Standard
Service Type:           L1-L3
Starts:                 08/10/12
Ends:                   08/10/15
```

I have no idea how these subscriptions are even managed. I've certainly not had to do anything to VM2 in the year or so since I've used it. Can anyone tell from that output what the original VM is missing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's any number of issues you could be seeing, but there's a handful of things I would check first.  I'm not super-familiar with RHEL's subscriptions (although certainly I've run yum more than a couple times), but I would start with investigating the SSL connection/certs  - apologize if your troubleshooting has already done all this.

1. Check the system time on both systems.  `date` Certificates are very sensitive to timing issues (or, more specifically, frequently date issues), and any time I have a cert problem, I start with checking my system time and comparing it against any ssl-oriented applications or certs I have.  It's not exactly clear what the status of your VM1 was, but if it's been turned off or unplugged, who knows what the clock has been doing?  Which brings us to point 2.
2. Check the validity of your Certificate Authority certs.  I would start with the certs in your yum configuration (typically found in the configuration /etc/yum.conf).  You might play with some of the verify options, like `-CAfile` if you're using some kind of custom configuration.
   openssl verify /path/to/ssl/certs
3. Also, I'm not sure if you found this article in your research, but it seems like it could be relevant, also.  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/189533

If you could provide the output from `yum update` it might shed a little more light on how to look.